# How to display different components with similar routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

How to display different components with similar routes?
There are two routes:

```
<Route exact path="/about/:name" component={About}> // <About />
<Route exact path="/about/static" component={StaticAbout}> // <StaticAbout />


<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/">
     <Home />
  </Route>
  <Route exact path="/about/:name">
     <About />
   </Route>
   <Route exact path="/about/static">
     <Dashboard />
   </Route>
</Switch>
```

Now the component that comes first in the list of routes is displayed, but how to display different components? This is for breadcrumbs.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-forked-8uw435?file=/example.js

Comment: You can't use two component in same route. Please read the concept of `Layout`

Comment: The code in the sandbox appears correct (*same as your code snippet*) and works as I'd expect it to. It's unclear what you are asking for help with. Please clarify what the issue is. What do you mean by "a similar route"? What different components are you trying to render? What breadcrumbs are you referring to? See [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

```
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
         <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/about/static">
         <Dashboard />
       </Route>
      <Route exact path="/about/:name">
         <About />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
```

The **static** route must be mentioned initially, such that the **static** route is not seen as a **dynamic** route.